# Dequeuing Multiple Completions With GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm attempting to use [`GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getqueuedcompletionstatusex) to dequeue multiple completions from an I/O Completion Port (IOCP).

```
void GetPackets() {
    OVERLAPPED_ENTRY pEntries;
    ULONG NumEntries;
    if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx(PointIOCP, &pEntries, PENDING_RECVS, &NumEntries, 0, false)) {
        printf("Get Queued Completion Status - Point Error: %i\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (NumEntries = 0) { return; }

    printf("Got Entries!\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NumEntries; i++) {
        NetPacket_Recv* Packet = reinterpret_cast<NetPacket_Recv*>(pEntries[i].lpOverlapped);
    }
}
```

The error is with `pEntries[i].lpOverlapped`. The compiler is telling me no `[]` operator exists for `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY`. According to the documentation `pEntries` should receive an array of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` structures.

> lpCompletionPortEntries: Receives an array of OVERLAPPED_ENTRY structures that hold the entries.

I'm only declaring a single instance of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` when I define `pEntries`. **How do I define `pEntries` to be a pointer to an array of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quoted from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/getqueuedcompletionstatusex-func), but you seem to have missed the important part *above* the snippet you quoted:

> *lpCompletionPortEntries* [out]
>
> **On input, points to a pre-allocated array of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` structures.**
>
> On output, receives an array of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` structures that hold the entries. The number of array elements is provided by *ulNumEntriesRemoved*.

`OVERLAPPED_ENTRY pEntries;` declares a *single* `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY`, not an *array* of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` elements.  That is why `pEntries[i]` does not work, because `pEntries` is not an array (or even a pointer).

When you pass `&pEntries` to the function, you are passing in a pointer to 1 `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY`, but you are setting the `ulCount` pointer to `PENDING_RECVS`, so the function is expecting you to pass in a pointer to an array containing at last `PENDING_RECVS` number of `OVERLAPPED_ENTRY` elements in it.  You are not doing that (unless `PENDING_RECVS` is 1).

Also, `NumEntries = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison.  You should have gotten a compiler warning about that.  You need to use `operator==` instead of `operator=`.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void GetPackets() {
    OVERLAPPED_ENTRY Entries[PENDING_RECVS];
    ULONG NumEntries = 0;
    if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx(PointIOCP, Entries, PENDING_RECVS, &NumEntries, 0, FALSE)) {
        printf("Get Queued Completion Status - Point Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (NumEntries == 0) { return; }

    printf("Got Entries!\n");
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < NumEntries; ++i) {
        NetPacket_Recv* Packet = reinterpret_cast<NetPacket_Recv*>(Entries[i].lpOverlapped);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, good eye on the `==` also. It is working as intended now. I assumed I could pass in a null pointer of the correct type and the function would set my pointer to some internal initialized variable. Thank you.

Comment: @KKlouzal "*I assumed I could pass in a null pointer of the correct type and the function would set my pointer to some internal initialized variable*" - you assumed incorrectly. Nothing in the documentation claims passing in a NULL pointer is valid. Nor does it make sense to do so. Nor was there any NULL pointer being used in your code anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make it:

```
OVERLAPPED_ENTRY entries[10];
```

(or some other maximum number you would like to return) instead, just like any other array. And pass the number of instances as the third parameter to GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx. (note how I changed the variable name as it is not actually a pointer). The function parameter is a pointer but the array variable is not.